# Find all numbers $n \in \Bbb Z$ such that $2n^2+3n-2$ and $n^2+1$ are coprime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Find all numbers $n \in \Bbb Z$ such that $2n^2+3n-2$ and $n^2+1$ are coprime.

I used Euclidean algorithm and got 
$(2n^2+3n-2,n^2+1)=(3n-4,n^2+1)=(3n-4,4n+3)=(3n-4,12n+9)=(3n-4,25)$

then I checked it when

$n=1 \implies (3,2)=1$

$n=2 \implies (12,5)=1$

$n=3 \implies (25,10) \neq 1$

is it somehow useful? What should I do next?

Comment: What you've done is correct. You want to find $n$ such that $3n-4$ is not a multiple of $5$.

Comment: ... which boils down to solving Diophantine equation $3n - 4 = 5m$.

Comment: @Ennar I think it's easier to say, it boils down to solving the congruence $3n\equiv4\bmod5$, which is the same as $3n\equiv9\bmod5$, which is $n\equiv3\bmod5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've done your algebra correctly, you have shown that if they have a nontrivial gcd then they're both divisible by five. Now $n^2+1$ is divisible by five precisely when $n$ is two more than, or two less than, a multiple of five.  The other polynomial is divisible by five when $n$ is two less than a multiple of five, but not when $n$ is two more than a multiple of five. So the answer is, exactly when $n$ is two less than a multiple of five. (That is, those are the values of $n$ for which the two numbers are *not* coprime).

Comment: Thanks. But how to find n such that $2n^2+3n-2=0(mod5)?$ I've done it with $n^2+1$ easily.

Comment: Just check $n=0,1,2,3,4\bmod5$ in turn. Or factorise: $(2n-1)(n+2)=0\bmod5$, ie $2(n-3)(n+2)=0\bmod5$ ie $n=3\bmod5$.

Comment: Working modulo five, $2n^2+3n-2=2n^2-12n+18=2(n^2-6n+9)=2(n-3)^2$.